# Map struct : When source is null, target should NOT be set to null

Tags: java, null, target, mapstruct

I am trying to map nested properties using mapstruct 1.2.0.CR2. 
(Example map *customer.address.houseNumber* to  *userDTO.homeDTO.addressDTO.houseNo* ).

**Expectation :** I do not want to set the  addressDTO to null when  customer.address is null.    Since addressDTO contains  "countyname" and other properties which  are already set from other different sources.

Please advice if there is property/setting that I could set so that the target it not set to null when source is null.

```
@Mapper( nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS )
public interface CustomerUserMapperNullCheck {

    @Mapping(source="address", target="homeDTO.addressDTO" )
    void mapCustomer(Customer customer, @MappingTarget  UserDTO userDTO)  ;

    @Mapping(source="houseNumber", target="houseNo" )
    void mapCustomerHouse(Address address, @MappingTarget  AddressDTO addrDTO)  ;

}
```

I initially tried in single mapping like below

```
@Mapping(target="homeDTO.addressDTO.houseNo", source="address.houseNumber")
 abstract void mapCustomerHouse(Customer customer, @MappingTarget  UserDTO userDTO)  ;
```

Then tried splitting up the mapping,  based on https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/649.

Both  approaches does not produce the expected result/
Generated method code

```
 protected void customerToHomeDTO(Customer customer, HomeDTO mappingTarget) {
        if ( customer == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( customer.getAddress() != null ) {
            if ( mappingTarget.getAddressDTO() == null ) {
                mappingTarget.setAddressDTO( new AddressDTO() );
            }
            mapCustomerHouse( customer.getAddress(), mappingTarget.getAddressDTO() );
        }
        **else {
            mappingTarget.setAddressDTO( null );   // I dont want to else where addressDTO is set to null.
        }**
    }
```

The complete generated code is here
  https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1306

Thanks

Comment: Did the answer in the linked issue solved your problem?

Comment: For me it works as explained in the link provided in the issue/question.

Answer (score 38):

```
@Mapper( nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE )
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked like this:

```
@Mapper(nullValueMappingStrategy =  NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)
public interface MyMapper {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me only this one works, as explained here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/649

```
@Mapper( nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS )
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
@BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy =  NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
void updateProduct(@MappingTarget Product entity, ProductRequestDto dto);
```

@Mapping annotation requires "target" option in current (1.5.5.Final) MapStruct release.

Thanks for @tak3shi link on github discussion!

Comment: Adding MappingTarget adnotation as well as BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy did the trick for me. It seems that without MappingTarget mapper implementation generates but ignoring nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Mapstruct `1.5.5.Final`

You can use `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE` at mapper level to affect all your mapping methods:

```
    @Mapper(
        nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE
    )
    public interface MyMapper {..}
```

If you want just to override the mapping for a single value, you can use `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE` at mapping level and define a custom mapping method:

```
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "json", source = "json", 
                 qualifiedByName = "jsonCustomMapper", 
                 nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ON_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION)
    })
    Target target(Source source);
    
    ...

    @Named("jsonCustomMapper")
    default String jsonCustomMapper(String json) {
        // Define empty json for null or empty json string
        return (json == null || json.trim().isEmpty()) ? "{}" :json;
    }
```

Note that `ON_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION` does not affect custom mapping methods.
https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/NullValueCheckStrategy.html#ON_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION

Hope this is useful for you.